# Как сделать авторизацию на сайте в android приложении с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, android, post, авторизация, jsoup

Большая просьба не кидать камнями а написать по делу либо скинуть ссылку на уже готовые гайды по созданию авторизации на сайте. Перерыл весь гугл - ничего рабочего так и не нашел(Руки не из заднего места) сам по себе начинающий кодер на java, но структуру кода понимаю(Что, где и от чего зависит). Нужен готовый пример с рабочим пост запросом, единственное из того что нашел хоть как то давало признаки жизни.

```
try {
    Connection.Response res1 = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru")
            .data("login","admin")
            .data("passwd","admin")
            .data("send","Войти")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();
    Map loginCoockies = res1.cookies();
    System.out.println(loginCoockies);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru")
            .cookies(loginCoockies)
            .get();
    System.out.println(doc);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
return null;
```

После запуска выдает:

> {PHPSESSID=t7idbm5jkr40ial25brvju72n2}

и html код страницы.

Точнее после каждого нажатия на кнопку выдает PHPSESSID=(Всегда разный). Страница html кода показывает что я так и не был авторизован.

Comment: Пробовал отправлять POST-запрос при помощи готовых программ или утилит или плагинов для браузера, всё работает так, как ожидалось?

Comment: Пробовал делать авторизацию на Delphi, все работает.

Comment: @ДимаФилософ интересуется: *«Добрый день . Не могу пока оставлять комментарий, поэтому приходится записывать так. Я тоже интересуюсь подобным вопросом. И хотел узнать, могли бы вы поделиться с тем, что смогли сделать. Я был бы очень признателен, если бы вы отправили ссылку на репозиторий. Спасибо.»*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разобрался сам, авторизация проходит успешно, проверка тоже.
Скачал HTTP Analyzer и посмотрел какие данные отправляются POST запросом и куда.
Добавил в запрос недостающих данных, и все заработало )